# test class error - attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger using oldmap

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, null-pointer, trigger-oldmap

I am receiving an Error in my Test class, but am unsure of the reason why.
Here is the Error:

> Exception: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0i4C000000HfieQAC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TABLoan_beforeupdate: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>
> Class.TestTABLoan_beforeupdate.testTABbeforeupdate: line 30, column 1
>
> Trigger.TABLoan_beforeupdate: line 9, column 1: []

Below is the Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestTABLoan_beforeupdate {
    static testMethod void testTABbeforeupdate() {
        //Create records to test
        Account myAccount = new Account();
        myAccount.Name = 'My Awesome Account';
        myAccount.Industry  = 'Energy';
        myAccount.Type = 'Association';
        myAccount.RecordTypeId = [Select Id,SobjectType,Name From RecordType WHERE Name ='Business' and SobjectType ='Account'  limit 1].Id;
        insert myAccount; 

        Opportunity myopportunity = new Opportunity();
        myopportunity.Name = 'My Opportunity ties to a lead.';
        myopportunity.Account = myAccount;
        myopportunity.StageName = 'Applicant'; 
        myopportunity.CloseDate = Date.today();
        insert myopportunity;     

        LLC_BI__Loan__c myLoan = new LLC_BI__Loan__c();
        myLoan.Name = 'This Lead has an Opportunity,';
        myLoan.Opportunity_Source__c = myopportunity.Id;
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c = 3000000;
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Account__c = myAccount.Id;
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Product_Line__c = 'ABL';
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Product_Type__c = 'ABL';
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Product__c = 'Other';
        insert myLoan;

        myLoan.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c = 250000;
        update myLoan;

        myopportunity = [SELECT Id, PrincipalBalance__c From Opportunity LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(myopportunity.PrincipalBalance__c, 250000);
    }
}
```

And here is the trigger I am testing:

```
trigger TABLoan_beforeupdate on LLC_BI__Loan__c (before update) {

    List<LLC_BI__Loan__c> loans = new List<LLC_BI__Loan__c>();
    for (LLC_BI__Loan__c l : Trigger.new){
        // Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
        LLC_BI__Loan__c oldl = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.id);
        // Check to see if loan has principal balance and Opportunity source
        if ((oldl.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c != l.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c) && (l.Opportunity_Source__c != null )) {
            l.Opportunity_Source__r.PrincipalBalance__c = l.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c;
            loans.add(l);   
        }
    }
    update loans;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack track for the error you are receiving?

Comment: On the trigger, you probably don't need the update DML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it, your error is pointing to this particular line in your trigger:

```
l.Opportunity_Source__r.PrincipalBalance__c = l.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c;
```

You're trying to update a field on a related object, which doesn't work (as you've found out).

Trigger context variables do not contain related data (fields on related objects), only the fields for the object that a given trigger is defined on (`LLC_BI__Loan__c` in your case).

A few changes you should make to get things working:

#### Change your trigger to be an `after update` trigger

Salesforce recommends using an after trigger when you are setting/updating fields on an object that is different than the one the trigger is defined on.

You're also not updating any fields on any `LLC_BI__Loan__c` records, so there's no benefit to using a 'before' trigger here anyway.

#### Make use of your ability to set an Id in an sObject constructor

Normally, if you want to update a record, you'd query for that record, make changes to it, and then DML `update` it.

If you have the `Id` of the record you want to update, you don't need to query at all!

In your case, updating the related `Opportunity_Source__c` (just guessing that it isn't a standard `Opportunity`) would look something like this

```
 for (LLC_BI__Loan__c l : Trigger.new){
    LLC_BI__Loan__c oldl = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.id);
    if ((oldl.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c != l.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c) && (l.Opportunity_Source__c != null )) {
        // Use the sObject constructor to set the Id
        // This allows us to update a record without querying for it first.
        Opportunity_Source__c oppSourceForUpdate = new Opportunity_Source__c(
            // Inside this constructor, we use commas to separate fields.
            // Do not use semicolons in here!
            Id = l.Opportunity_Source__c,
            PrincipalBalance__c = l.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c
        );

        // This is a list, and would need to be defined outside of your loop
        recordsToUpdate.add(oppSourceForUpdate); 
    }
}
// Outside of all loops, safe to perform DML
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because you are referencing a field across a relationship in your trigger.

```
l.Opportunity_Source__r.PrincipalBalance__c
```

l.Opportunity_Source__r ... will not have any field values in it, the trigger only lazy-loads referenced fields on the actual objects going through the trigger.

You will need to collect a Set<Id> of all the Opportunity_Source__c records you need, load them into a Map<Id, sObject> so you can then get them back when you need to reference them in your loop. (this approach is a best practise for bulk-friendly triggers).